# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so

Tags: php, centos, memcached, yum, centos6.5

I'm working with `CentOS 6.5`

When I'm executing this `php -v`

I'm getting the below message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcached.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.4.36 (cli) (built: Dec 19 2014 06:28:27)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

As it seems to be a `memcached` error, when I'm trying this

`yum install memcached.x86_64 php-pecl-memcache.x86_64`

I'm getting below mentioned errors:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * rpmforge: mirror.team-cymru.org
drivesrvr                                                                                                                                        | 2.2 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package memcached.x86_64 0:1.4.4-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libevent-1.4.so.2()(64bit) for package: memcached-1.4.4-3.el6.x86_64
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.5-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libevent.x86_64 0:1.4.13-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 0:3.0.5-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
Error: Package: php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed php from "remi" repository which is not enabled by default.
So you need to enable it to install additional PHP extension, with correct ABI compatibility.

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-pecl-memcache
```

Read the FAQ : http://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#enable

Comment: What if I don't want the php installation from remi, instead I would like to have that from base, any suggestion on that.

Comment: You already have php 5.4 from "remi" repo, so if you want only base packages, you have to downgrade to 5.3.3.